# Codeigniter pagination with modified table

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, pagination

I am new to codeigniter and has no absolute knowledge on how to do pagination.
I watched some video tutorials and read some articles on how I could implement it on codeigniter, but my problem is quite different.

I have an invoice table that is displayed to my view. I use PHP to create the table and `foreach` to scan through rows of data. What's making it more complicated is the addition of fields like hyperlinked actions such as Edit and Print. I am still on early stages of development but I can already see the problem of having too many rows displayed in this page. What's interesting is that I also added some search filters to the table.

Here's a code of how I create my table:

```
<?php
echo '<th>Date</th><th>Invoice #</th><th>Customer</th><th>Amount Due</th><th>Total</th><th>Status</th><th>Actions</th>';
foreach ($invoices as $a) {

    if ($a->statusID == 1)
        $status = '<span value = "'. $a->statusID .'" class="label label-success">PAID</span>';
    elseif ($a->statusID == 2)
        $status = '<span value = "'. $a->statusID .'" class="label label-warning">PARTIAL</span>';
    elseif ($a->statusID == 4)
        $status = '<span value = "'. $a->statusID .'" class="label label-default">SAVED</span>';
    elseif ($a->statusID == 5)
        $status = '<span value = "'. $a->statusID .'" class="label label-danger">OVERDUE</span>';

    echo '<tr><td>'.$a->dateCreated.'</td><td>'.$a->invoiceNumber.'</td><td>'.$a->companyName.'</td><td>'.number_format($a->amountDue,2).'</td><td>'.number_format($a->totalAmount,2).'</td><td>'.$status.'</td><td>';
    echo '<a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Edit" href="invoice_new?id='.$a->invoiceNumber.'" onclick="retrieveInvoice('. $a->invoiceNumber.'); return false;" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit editButton" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:10px;"></span></a>';
    echo '<a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Add Payment" href="invoice_payment?id='.$a->invoiceNumber.'" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:10px;"></span></a>';
    echo '<a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Print" href="printing/printInvoice?id='.$a->invoiceNumber.'" target="_blank"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-right:10px;"></span></a>';                            
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>'; 

}?>
```

From what I observed, you can create pagination provided you're not going to touch the table fetched from DB. I hope I'm wrong about that.

Here's an image of my page. Thank you for spending time to read my problem. Sorry for my english. Cheers!

[image]

Comment: Have you considered a js solution ? See this jquery lib for example : http://www.datatables.net/

Comment: I will look into it and post some results if I will be able to integrate this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [Codeigniter pagination](https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html):

1. Load libraries and helpers:

   ```
   $this->load->library('pagination');
   $this->load->helper("url");
   ```
2. Pass the config variables, initialize and create links:

   ```
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/index.php/test/page/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->Your_Model->count_all_results();;
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
    $choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
    $config["num_links"] = round($choice);
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
   ```
3. You can format links with Bootstrap (see these answers at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14181638/3088475)):

   ```
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';            
    $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo; Previous';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next &raquo;';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
   ```
4. Pass variables to your model and your view:

   ```
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data["rows"] = $this->Your_model->your_function($config["per_page"],$page);
    $this->load->view('your_view', $data);
   ```

Check out these useful links at [SitePoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/) and [FormGet](http://www.formget.com/pagination-in-codeigniter/).

I hope all this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem with this method is that I don't think it can handle table data modification on the view page such as adding columns for editing and printing. This instruction is good for data coming directly from the database.